# How to cancel display: none;

Tags: css

I have a code like this:

```
<div id="advertisement-template" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

and there is an element like this inside

```
<script type="text/javascript">
....................
....................
....................
        });
    </script>
```

When I use `<script type="...` element by itself it works but when it is inside `<div id="advertisement-template" style="display:none;">`
 it doesn't show up. I cannot change anything above or inside `<div id="advertisement-template" style="display:none;">`, I can only put something between `<div id="advertisement-template" style="display:none;">` and `</div>` to make the element show up.

I have checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654068/remove-attribute-displaynone-so-the-item-will-be-visible/3654074) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009894/css-disable-display-none) but haven't found a solution.

I don't know much about coding yet but I need a solution for this problem. Please help.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what works and what does not work? That will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I would not recommend this but if it is inevitable you could use this in style tag or in stylesheet  #advertisement-template[style]{ display:block !important; } to override the inline-style.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You can put a <script> inside the div? Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/edntp1bq/)? But it doesn't work in your setup? Then either I don't understand the question, or you need to explain more about your setup.

Answer (score -1):

**pls try below jquery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#advertisement-template").removeAttr("style");
    });
</script>
```