# Remove the display:none attribute so that the item will be visible

Tags: powershell, selenium

I need to remove the display:none attribute so that the item will be visible.
It is similar to [remove attribute display:none; so the item will be visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654068/remove-attribute-displaynone-so-the-item-will-be-visible) although I am using Powershell with Selenium.

The textarea Element is:

```
<textarea id="response" name="response" class="response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

I need to display this text area.

No luck with any of this commands:

```
$TextArea_Element.show()
$TextArea_Element.displayed.Clear()
$TextArea_Element.sendKeys("displayed".DELETE)
```

If I do a `$TextArea_Element.displayed` I get a value of "False"

Here is my Powershell code:

```
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$url = "somesite.com"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($url)

ForEach ($TextArea_Element in (Find-SeElement -Driver $browser -TagName TextArea))
{ 
  $TextArea_Element
  $TextArea_Element.displayed.Clear()
  #$TextArea_Element.sendKeys("displayed".DELETE)
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the (ultimately Java) type that `Find-SeElement` (`Get-SeElement`) returns is of type [`RemoteWebElement`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html) - and it doesn't look like it allows you to _modify_ the underlying HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit the style of element to `display='block'`.

You can apply JavaScript to element as below:

```
$browser.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.display='block';", $TextArea_Element)
```

Comment: @hdsouza Could you accept my answer if that's helpful for you :)